# Write-Only pointer type

Tags: c++, c, pointers, readonly, const-correctness

I'm writing software for an embedded system.

We are using pointers to access registers of an FPGA device.
Some of the registers are read-only, while others are write-only.

The write-only registers will produce undefined values when read.

I want to define a pointer type that will allow the compiler to detect when reading values from a write-only registers (a.k.a. dereferencing).

Can a write-only pointer be created using only C language syntax?
(We are developing first prototype using C, but moving to C++ on 2nd generation.)

How can an efficient write-only pointer be created in C++?
(Remember, this is not tracking items in dynamic memory, but accessing hardware addresses.)

This code is used on an embedded system where safety and quality are highest concerns.

Comment: You have also read-write registers, right?

Comment: I seriously doubt that you can do it in C. In C++, on the other hand, you should be able to do it relatively easily.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In C and in C++ the only solution is discipline. Writing `*p = ...` or `... = *p` is always shorter and more tempting than writing and using some special macros, functions or classes (possibly template classes).

Comment: @Alexey Not so. Have a look at Jerry’s answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well in C you could hide them behind an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) with well-defined read / write functions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph As I said, you have to write that and stick to using it. That's discipline.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio: Only a few are read and write.  I'm trying to be proactive and have the compiler flag write-only registers that somebody is reading.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ok. I stubbed a very quick&dirty answer.

Comment: @Alexey I fail to see your point. It’s as much disciplin as using `int` instead of `std::string`: none, really. Once you’ve declared your variables of the appropriate type the compiler makes sure you don’t use them wrong.

Comment: I think I understand and agree with both Alexey and Konrad.  Alexey is right that you can't prevent the possibility of it being read - similar to `const` correctness, anything you do is more of a soft guarantee, which is 1 typecast or bad pointer dereference away from being broken.  On the other hand, Konrad and others are right that you can build abstractions that make this less likely - smart pointers in C++, accessor functions and incomplete types in C, etc.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Who are these people writing code for this platform who don't understand that some registers are read/write only and cannot quickly grasp the patterns present in the current codebase?  People like that should probably not be maintaining this system.  When you write code for small, niche platforms you take the time to understand what you are doing.

Comment: C has write-only source code, not data.

Comment: @EdS. These people are newbies and pros and everyone in-between. While I'm more on the pro side, I do sometimes make silly mistakes that cost me up to an hour of debugging. It happens.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Sure, but it's hard to imagine they wouldn't quickly pick up patterns used all over the place.

Comment: Please excuse my complete ignorance, but what would the point of a write-only register be?

Comment: @MikeyCee:  Digital to Analog Converter (DAC), LED, LCD, UART Transmit register, anything that only needs to be controlled or set but does not *need* to be read back.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I'd probably write a tiny wrapper class for each:

```
template <class T>
class read_only {
    T volatile *addr;
public:
    read_only(int address) : addr((T *)address) {}
    operator T() volatile const { return *addr; }
};

template <class T>
class write_only { 
    T volatile *addr;
public:
    write_only(int address) : addr ((T *)address) {}

    // chaining not allowed since it's write only.
    void operator=(T const &t) volatile { *addr = t; } 
};
```

At least assuming your system has a reasonable compiler, I'd expect both of these to be optimized so the generated code was indistinguishable from using a raw pointer. Usage:

```
read_only<unsigned char> x(0x1234);
write_only<unsigned char> y(0x1235);

y = x + 1;         // No problem

x = y;             // won't compile
```

Comment: Nice templates! How do you combine them for read-write registers?

Comment: Why did you choose to use `int` and not `volatile T*`? If you actually want an integer, there is `intptr_t`. Also, `operator T()` could be `const volatile`.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I avoided `T volatile*` because that would mean the user having a read/write pointer to the register -- exactly what we wanted to avoid. Embedded compilers are often somewhat...limited, so expecting them to include `intptr_t` (just added in C++11) is asking a lot. If anything, I'd make it a template parameter. I agree about `const volatile` -- just edited; thank you.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio: If you want read/write, I'm not sure what you'd gain over just a `volatile T *`. I suppose if you want, you can create something to avoid explicit dereferencing, but relationship to these templates would be purely...spiritual -- it'd have both `operator T` and `operator =` to do reading and writing.

Comment: +1.  Since write-only is hard to debug, having isolated the writes to a function gives you a nice spot to add logging.  I'm still concerned about cavalierly using int for an address.  The last embedded system I worked on had 16-bit ints but 32-bit addresses.  I would make a typedef for an address and use that, so it's easy to re-purpose the code for other systems.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: A typedef could work too, but as I said above, if I were to change it from int, I'd probably just use a template parameter. For testing, you can also create a class that stores (and allows retrieval of) the last value that was written, so the rest of the code can treat it like read/write memory.

Answer (score 8):

I would use a combination of structs to rappresent the register and a pair of functions to handle them.

In a `fpga_register.h` you would have something like

```
#define FPGA_READ = 1; 
#define FPGA_WRITE = 2;
typedef struct register_t {
    char permissions;
} FPGARegister;

FPGARegister* fpga_init(void* address, char permissions);

int fpga_write(FPGARegister* register, void* value);

int fpga_read(FPGARegister* register, void* value);
```

with READ and WRITE in xor to express permissions.

Than in the `fpga_register.c` you would define a new struct

```
typedef struct register_t2 {
    char permissions;
    void * address;
} FPGARegisterReal;
```

so that you returns a pointer to it instead of a pointer to `FPGARegister` on `fpga_init`.

Then, on `fpga_read` and `fpga_write` you check the permissions and

- if the operetion is allowed, cast back the `FPGARegister` from the argument to a `FPGARegisterReal`, execute the desired action (set or read the value) and return a success code
- if the operation is not allowed, just return an error code

This way, no one including the header file will be able to access the `FPGARegisterReal` structure, and thus it will not have direct access to the register address. Obviously, one could hack it, but I'm quite sure that such intentional hacks are not your actual concerns.

Answer (score 8):

I've worked with a lot of hardware, and some of which has "read only" or "write only" registers (or different functions depending on whether you read or write to the register, which makes for fun when someone decides to do "reg |= 4;" instead of remembering the value it should have, set bit 2 and write the new value, like you should. Nothing like trying to debug hardware that has random bits appearing and disappearing from registers you can't read! ;) I have so far not seen any attempts of actually blocking reads from a write-only register, or writes to read-only registers.

By the way, did I say that having registers that are "write only" is a REALLY bad idea, because you can't read back to check if the software has set the register correctly, which makes debugging really hard - and people writing drivers don't like debugging hard problems that could be made really easy by two lines of VHDL or Verilog code.

If you have some control over the register layout, I would suggest that you put "readonly" registers at a 4KB-aligned address, and "writeonly" registers in another 4KB-aligned address [more than 4KB is fine]. Then you can program the memory controller of the hardware to prevent the access.

Or, let the hardware produce an interrupt if registers that aren't supposed to be read are being read, or registers that aren't supposed to be written are written. I presume the hardware does produce interrupts for other purposes?

The other suggestions made using various C++ solutions are fine, but it doesn't really stop someone who is intent on using the registers directly, so if it's really a safety concern (rather than "let's make it awkward"), then you should have hardware to protect against the misuse of the hardware.

Comment: This is a good point where it applies, but reading back values doesn't always make conceptual sense, such as a register that appends to a fifo every time you write to it.

Comment: @Owen: It is still useful to be able to read back "what was the last thing I wrote to this register". But yes, I agree, there are some registers where that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Having write-only registers is a perfectly fine idea if register writes trigger *actions*.  While it may be helpful to have read-only registers which then report the status of those actions, and such registers might even share an address with the write-only registers, the address wouldn't really have a read-write register, but rather a read-only register and a separate write-only register.

Answer (score 7):

In C, you can use pointers to incomplete types to prevent all dereferencing:

---

```
/* writeonly.h */
typedef struct writeonly *wo_ptr_t;
```

---

```
/* writeonly.c */
#include "writeonly.h"

struct writeonly {
  int value 
};

/*...*/

   FOO_REGISTER->value = 42;
```

---

```
/* someother.c */
#include "writeonly.h"

/*...*/

   int x = FOO_REGISTER->value; /* error: deref'ing pointer to incomplete type */
```

---

Only `writeonly.c`, or in general any code that has a definition `struct writeonly`, can dereference the pointer.  That code, of course, can accidentally read the value also, but at least all other code is prevented from dereferencing the pointers all together, while being able to pass those pointers around and store them in variables, arrays and structures.

`writeonly.[ch]` could provide a function for writing a value.

Answer (score 6):

I see no elegant way of doing it in C. I do however see a way of doing it:

```
#define DEREF_PTR(type, ptr) type ptr; \
typedef char ptr ## _DEREF_PTR;

#define NO_DEREF_PTR(type, ptr) type ptr; \

#define DEREFERENCE(ptr) \
*ptr; \
{ptr ## _DEREF_PTR \
attempt_to_dereference_pointer_ ## ptr;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DEREF_PTR(int*, x)
    NO_DEREF_PTR(int*, y);

    DEREFERENCE(x);
    DEREFERENCE(y); // will throw an error
}
```

This has the benefit of giving you static error checking. Of course, using this method, you'll have to go out and modify all of your pointer declarations to use macros, which is probably not a whole lot of fun.

**Edit:**
As described in the comments.

```
#define READABLE_PTR(type, ptr) type ptr; \
typedef char ptr ## _READABLE_PTR;

#define NON_READABLE_PTR(type, ptr) type ptr; \

#define GET(ptr) \
*ptr; \
{ptr ## _READABLE_PTR \
attempt_to_dereference_non_readable_pointer_ ## ptr;}

#define SET(ptr, value) \
*ptr = value;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    READABLE_PTR(int*, x)
    NON_READABLE_PTR(int*, y);

    SET(x, 1);
    SET(y, 1);

    int foo = GET(x);
    int bar = GET(y); // error
}
```

Comment: Whoops, that's correct. I saw his mention of detecting dereferencing and sort of got ahead of myself.

Comment: However, the same principle could be used to define macros for reading and setting the value behind the pointer.

Comment: @MartinSvanberg Nevertheless I'd like to understand it a bit more... can you explain how it was intended to work?

Comment: If you have a pointer `x` defined as a pointer that can be dereferenced (`DEREF_PTR(int*, x)`), the preprocessor also defines a type behind the scenes called `x_DEREF_PTR`. When a call to `DEREFERENCE` is made, it instantiates a variable of this type in a separate scope. For pointers defined with `NO_DEREF_PTR`, this type doesn't exist, and so an error is thrown.

Comment: @MartinSvanberg in the updated version does not allow read-only pointers, does it?

Comment: @GiacomoTesio Nope, but it's possible to add that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Saks has a Youtube presentation, that I couldn't, find where he introduces write-only registers for embedded devices.

Fortunately he wrote an article, that was easier to search, here: https://www.embedded.com/how-to-enforce-write-only-access/

This is the code from the article, updated for C++11

```
class write_only_T{
public:
    write_only_T(){}
    write_only_T(T const& v) : m(v){}
    write_only_T(T&& v) : m(std::move(v)){}
    write_only_T& operator=(T const& v){
        m = v;
        return *this;
    }
    write_only_T& operator=(T&& v){
        m = std::move(v);
        return *this;
    }
    write_only_T(write_only_T const&) = delete;
    write_only_T(write_only_T&&) = delete;
    write_only_T& operator=(write_only_T const&) = delete;
    write_only_T& operator=(write_only_T&&) = delete;
private:
    T m;
};
```

I don't think you need a special pointer type if you used this because write-only is a property of the value, but I can imagine a synthetic pointer-type that skips the value type.
Likely you will need to introduce a write-only reference-type and so on.