# Give an optimizer greater "License"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I know the concept behind `volatile` variables.  Basically all reads and writes to that variable **must** occur.  Is there a way to allow the optimizer to get away with only doing all of the writes and assuming that the reads will always stay the same (unless modified by writing).

Also (along the same lines) is there a way to define a new type of memory for the compiler to store variables.  For example if I have a micro controller with an SD card can I define the SD card as a place to store memory (or do I explicitly have to do all of the read/writes on my own).

For the record I am using gcc as my compiler if there is anything I can do specifically (and only) on gcc

Comment: to detect that variable is modified by write, compiler must generate code which .... reads variable

Comment: @Lashane But If it assumes that nothing is changed unless it writes to it (in other words no other thread will change it) it can tell if it is changed (theoretically)....

Comment: The answer is, "No."

Comment: @Lashane But I want to force it to do all of the writes....just don't care about rereading it everytime

Comment: Why do you care about writes but not reads?

Comment: So, do not read it unless it psychicly determines it would get a different answer if it did read it?  I wish!

Comment: @AlanStokes Because I want the data to actually be written to a register (which is read in a different process, but not modified).

Comment: One example is caching.  A write of a variable would go to the SDCard and also the cache.  A read would reference the cache.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Exactly

Comment: Related:  [Write-Only Pointer Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049329/write-only-pointer-type).  My question was at a higher level. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably what I am looking for:

```
template<class T>
class smartWriter{
    volatile T* Volatile;  //Use this for writes
    T* NotVol;  //Use this for reads
    public:
        smartWriter(T* add) : Volatile(add),NotVol(add){
        }
        operator T&() const{
            return *NotVol;  //reads involve the non volatile one
        }
        void operator=(T data){
            *Volatile = data;  //writes involve the volatile one
        }

};

int main(int argc,char** args){
    smartWriter<int> smtVar(((int*)0xdeadbeaf)) ;  //Initialize var with address "0xdeadbeef"
    smtVar = 12;  //Optimizer can not get rid of this
    int other = smtVar;  //Optimizer might get rid of this?

    system("Pause");
}
```

Thanks for sparking my imagination with the smart pointer thing....

Comment: Perhaps C++ is different, but from the C11 specification, *"If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @user3386109 Yes but I believe it is implicitly casted? (maybe)

Comment: @user3386109: there's a good chance this general idea is fine on many specific platforms.  If you're ok with checking the asm to make sure it works as expected on your actual target platform(s), then you don't always need to write strictly portable code.  I doubt this is like signed integer overflow, where the compiler actually tries to optimize based on the assumption that it can't happen.  (Undefined behaviour is still bad, though, much worse than "implementation-defined".)

Answer (score 4):

> I know the concept behind volatile variables.

ok...

> Basically all reads and writes to that variable must occur.

Not "basically", absolutely.

> Is there a way to allow the optimizer to get away with only doing all of the writes and assuming that the reads will always stay the same (unless modified by writing).

No

<- snip ->

volatile is there to model read/write access to memory mapped I/O. 'Writing' to such I/O often triggers activity in the electronics even if the value written is the same as the one previously written.

There is no other use for volatile - no, not even in multithreading (where it won't do what you wanted anyway).

From §7.1.6.1

> [ Note: volatile is a *hint* to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization involving the object
>   because the value of the object might be changed by means undetectable by an implementation. Furthermore,
>   for some implementations, volatile might indicate that special hardware instructions are required to access
>   the object. See 1.9 for detailed semantics. In general, the semantics of volatile are intended to be the
>   same in C++ as they are in C. — end note ]

The implication here being that unless you understand exactly what the implementation is doing with the volatile variable, you have no place using it.

It's use is not portable so if used at all, should be wrapped in an implementation-specific specialisation of whatever concept you are dealing with.

Comment: Volatile can also be used for mapping shared memory between tasks and processors.  My understanding is that if the memory location is modified outside of the program's control, the memory is volatile.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the c++ memory model has no concept of 'tasks' and 'processors'. It only understands threads if the memory access is protected by a memory fence such as std::atomic or std::mutex. volatile on its own is only useful in an implementation-defined way.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, which is the need for `volatile` (for anything outside of the current task or process that could modify the variable)

Comment: @DarthRubik yes, but it only has any meaning in an implementation-defined way. Added a quote from the standard to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

<del>How about simply casting away the volatility on reads?</del>

Turned out to not be simple, at all.

The following seems to only work reliably on clang. And only when making the hw_reg_read alias before doing the volatile write.

```
volatile int * hw_reg = (int*)0x0001003B;

int main()
{
    /*obtain nonvolatile alias*/
    int* hw_reg_read = const_cast<int*>(hw_reg);

    /*volatile write*/
    *hw_reg = 42;

    /*nonvolatile read*/
    int i = *hw_reg_read;

    return i;
}
```

I will leave it here as scarecrow, for now.

Comment: Checked it on godbolt. Doesn't work. The compiler doesn't cast away volatile in practice.

Comment: It would be possible to make that work in a compiler, but very difficult. I find it hard to believe any compiler writer ever bothered.

Comment: @RichardHodges Looks like you're right. I did get it working in spirit on clang, by making the nonvolatile read pointer before doing the volatile write. But this didnt work on any of the other compilers. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you could use a smart pointer, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049329/write-only-pointer-type).

You are talking of somehow giving a variable another attribute (at least).  If the variable has the given attribute then take different actions with accessing it (read or write).

For that, you would need to modify the compiler.  It's possible.  For example, the 8051 compilers have attributes that allow for bit access and page access of variables.  Many compilers for embedded systems have syntaxes for placing variables in specific memory blocks.

I recommend trying a smart-pointer wrapper first.

Another idea is to place the variables into a class and provide *getters* and *setters* to model your environment (don't allow direct access).

Comment: Only problem is I **don't** want it to be write only.  I only want the compiler to assume that no other process will write to it.... but I do want it to be write every time I tell it to

Comment: @DarthRubik so keep a non-volatile copy. Write both and read the copy.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added a post using the same basic idea as that post but in a different way